# How to diagnose Fatal Application Errors in WinCE?

Tags: windows-ce, sd-card

We recently moved our Windows CE application to the SD Card.

Since then the QA - Team reported some "Fatal Application Errors".

Our application is a .net application and we are using wrapper DLLs to access device specific hardware.

Is there a way to log or debug such an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use various "Remote Tools" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa936010.aspx) for debugging if you have access to platform builder.

There are tools such as Spy++ which are also available on MS VC Platform, which you can access through Tools Menu.

Alternatively, you can use Port-mortem debugging http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa936043.aspx technique or Post-mortem debugger itself if you are a member of ODM/OEM group who has license of WinCE.